# AWS CloudFormation: The security group 'sg-' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc'

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have this template code that I'm trying to implement to my ElasticBeanStalk app but it's referencing to my default vpc and I can't find how I can reference my own VPC not the default one.
This is my **YAML** code: (I just need to know how to reference my VpcID)

I tried to add some lines that I found in aws resources but they're not working: (each one in alone I did not use them together)

```
Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'

VpcId: String

       Vpc:
        Default: "vpc-"
        Type: String
      VpcCidr:
       Default: "10.0.0.0/16"
        Type: String
```

This is my original code:

```
    Resources:
  MyCacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Lock cache down to webserver access only"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort:
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName: CachePort
              DefaultValue: 11211
          ToPort:
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName: CachePort
              DefaultValue: 11211
          SourceSecurityGroupName:
            Ref: AWSEBSecurityGroup
  MyElastiCache:
    Type: 'AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster'
    Properties:
      CacheNodeType:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName: CacheNodeType
          DefaultValue: cache.t2.micro
      NumCacheNodes:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName: NumCacheNodes
          DefaultValue: 1
      Engine:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName: Engine
          DefaultValue: redis
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        -
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyCacheSecurityGroup
            - GroupId
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup :
    Metadata :
      ElastiCacheConfig :
        CacheName :
          Ref : MyElastiCache
        CacheSize :
           Fn::GetOptionSetting:
             OptionName : NumCacheNodes
             DefaultValue: 1
  WebServerUser : 
    Type : AWS::IAM::User
    Properties :
      Path : "/"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument :
            Statement :
              -
                Effect : Allow
                Action : 
                  - cloudformation:DescribeStackResource
                  - cloudformation:ListStackResources
                  - elasticache:DescribeCacheClusters
                Resource : "*"
  WebServerKeys :
    Type : AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties :
      UserName :
        Ref: WebServerUser

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Description: sample output only here to show inline string function parsing
    Value: |
      http://awseb-AWSEB-1U7AK1W53691K-1263338585.ca-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  MyElastiCacheName:
    Description: Name of the elasticache
    Value:
      Ref : MyElastiCache
  NumCacheNodes:
    Description: Number of cache nodes in MyElastiCache
    Value:
      Fn::GetOptionSetting:
        OptionName : NumCacheNodes
        DefaultValue: 1

files:
  "/etc/cfn/cfn-credentials" :
    content : |
      AWSAccessKeyId=`{ "Ref" : "WebServerKeys" }`
      AWSSecretKey=`{ "Fn::GetAtt" : ["WebServerKeys", "SecretAccessKey"] }`
    mode : "000400"
    owner : root
    group : root

  "/etc/cfn/get-cache-nodes" :
    content : |
      # Define environment variables for command line tools
      export AWS_ELASTICACHE_HOME="/home/ec2-user/elasticache/$(ls /home/ec2-user/elasticache/)"
      export AWS_CLOUDFORMATION_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/cfn
      export PATH=$AWS_CLOUDFORMATION_HOME/bin:$AWS_ELASTICACHE_HOME/bin:$PATH
      export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=/etc/cfn/cfn-credentials
      export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

      # Grab the Cache node names and configure the PHP page
      aws cloudformation list-stack-resources --stack `{ "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }` --region `{ "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }` --output text | grep MyElastiCache | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I {} aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --cache-cluster-id {} --region `{ "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }` --show-cache-node-info --output text | grep '^ENDPOINT' | awk '{print $2 ":" $3}' > `{ "Fn::GetOptionSetting" : { "OptionName" : "NodeListPath", "DefaultValue" : "/var/www/html/nodelist" } }`
    mode : "000500"
    owner : root
    group : root

  "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-cache-change.conf" :
    "content": |
      [cfn-cache-size-change]
      triggers=post.update
      path=Resources.AWSEBAutoScalingGroup.Metadata.ElastiCacheConfig
      action=/etc/cfn/get-cache-nodes
      runas=root

sources :
  "/home/ec2-user/elasticache" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticache-downloads/AmazonElastiCacheCli-latest.zip"

commands: 
  make-elasticache-executable:
    command: chmod -R ugo+x /home/ec2-user/elasticache/*/bin/*

packages : 
  "yum" :
    "aws-apitools-cfn"  : []

container_commands:
  initial_cache_nodes:
    command: /etc/cfn/get-cache-nodes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewrote the whole thing, in one file use this:

```
Resources:
  MyElastiCache:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster"
    Properties:
      CacheNodeType:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "CacheNodeType"
          DefaultValue : "cache.t2.micro"
      NumCacheNodes:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "NumCacheNodes"
          DefaultValue : "1"
      Engine:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "Engine"
          DefaultValue : "memcached"
      CacheSubnetGroupName:
        Ref: "MyCacheSubnets"
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref: "MemcachedSecurityGroup"
  MemcachedSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Lock cache down to webserver access only"
      VpcId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "VpcId"
      SecurityGroupIngress :
        - IpProtocol : "tcp"
          FromPort :
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName : "CachePort"
              DefaultValue: "11211"
          ToPort :
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName : "CachePort"
              DefaultValue: "11211"
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            Ref: "AWSEBSecurityGroup"
  MyCacheSubnets:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup"
    Properties:
      Description: "Subnets for ElastiCache"
      SubnetIds:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "CacheSubnets"
Outputs:
  ElastiCache:
    Description : "ID of ElastiCache Cache Cluster with Memcached"
    Value :
      Ref : "MyElastiCache"
```

And in another .config file use this:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption":
    CacheNodeType : cache.t2.micro
    NumCacheNodes : 1
    Engine : memcached
    CachePort : 11211
    CacheSubnets:
      - subnet-
      - subnet-
      - subnet-
    VpcId: vpc-
```

Answer (score 3):

`SourceSecurityGroupName` uses default VPC only, so if you are trying to use non-default VPC, you need to use `SourceSecurityGroupId`.

I was strugging to find why my setting doesn't work and finally found the documentation.

> You must specify the GroupName property or the GroupId property. For security groups that are in a VPC, you must use the GroupId property.
>
> [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-sourcesecuritygroupid)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your security group in your VPC using [VpcId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-vpcid) property:

```
  MyCacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Lock cache down to webserver access only"
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort:
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName: CachePort
              DefaultValue: 11211
          ToPort:
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName: CachePort
              DefaultValue: 11211
          SourceSecurityGroupName:
            Ref: AWSEBSecurityGroup
```

Comment: it's not working it's directly returning this error:

The configuration file .ebextensions/elasticache-iam-with-script.config in application version Sample Application-24 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: could not determine a constructor for the tag !Ref in "<reader>", line 7, column 14: VpcId: !Ref VpcId ^ , JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (R) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.